# Storing multi-dimensional array from database using numeric keys for the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I'm trying to get data from my database and store them in a multidimensional array, but it's not returning any rows for some reason. Before looking at my code, I would like to explain how I want the data to be stored in the multidimensional array. So, for example, here's a table:

```
Name  | Age | Sex
Harry | 18  | Male
Kate  | 18  | Female
```

After getting these from the database, I would like to store them in the multidimensional array like this:

```
$array[0][0] = "Harry";
$array[0][1] = "18";
$array[0][2] = "Male";
$array[1][0] = "Jane";
$array[1][1] = "18";
$array[1][2] = "Female";
```

**Code Part**

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

global $connect;
$fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM allData limit 2");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($fetch);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)){

  $count --;
  $arrayCount = count($myArray);

  $tempArrayCount = 0;
  while($tempArrayCount < $arrayCount){
  $array[$count][$tempArrayCount]= $row[$tempArrayCount];
  $tempArrayCount++;
  }

}

print_r($array);

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alls you need to do is this.

```
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQLI_NUM)){
      $array[] = $row;
    }
```